# string undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new with arrays, I wrote this piece of code here and I thought I had done everything syntax wise correctly. However, I get an

**C2065 'string': undeclared identifier**

As you can see I have my Prototypes set, and yet it still gives that error?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

//Prototypes:
void getJars(string[], int[], int);
int getTotal(string[], int[], int);

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string salsa[] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty" };
    const int NUM = 5;

    int jars[NUM];

    getJars(salsa, jars, NUM);
    getTotal(salsa, jars, NUM);



    return 0;
}

void getJars(string salsa[], int jars[], int NUM) {



cout << "Salsa Sales Calulator...\n";
cout << "------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {

        cout << "Please Insert the Jar Amount for Each Salsa: ";
        cout << salsa[i];
        cout << " ";
        cin >> jars[i];

        cout << endl;
    }


    return;
}
int getTotal(string salsa[], int jars[], int NUM) {

    int total;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {

        total += jars[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

I looked up the error on here, however, the solution they had come up with was to add the prototypes which most people forget however I did not forget and it still gives the error? Could anyone help??

Comment: just `#include <string>` will fix this for you.

Comment: Put `using namespace std;` before prototypes.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed: Or refer to the type as `std::string`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange these statements

```
void getJars(string[], int[], int);
int getTotal(string[], int[], int);

using namespace std;
```

Should be

```
using namespace std;

void getJars(string[], int[], int);
int getTotal(string[], int[], int);
```

Also initialize variable total

```
int getTotal(string salsa[], int jars[], int NUM) {

    int total = 0;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {

        total += jars[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

And update a typo

```
cout << "Salsa Sales Calculator...\n";
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And you can remove the `return` statement in function `getJars` because the function has return type `void`  and the `return` statement is not required for this function.

Comment: Ohh! wow, could you tell me why its like that?? Also Why was my post a bad question?? I thought it was a relevant question that people could search up> why did I get down voted??

Comment: @V.Martins There are many participants that only down vote questions instead of to answer them.:)

Comment: That's just sad, they should really find a way to fix that or at least limit the downvotes to first try to answer the question before you decide to downvote. Not everyone has all the expertise and experience. At least that way more people can learn and maintain their questions up for review. 

Well, Thank you,  Vlad, I'll make sure to keep this as a mental note for my other programs. You the Man!

Comment: @V.Martins No problem. I will up vote your question.:)

Comment: `using namespace std` is a really bad idea for setting up function declarations.   It would be better to fully qualify `string` as `std::string`, particularly if those declarations are ever placed in a header file.

Comment: @Peter All books for beginners are written with this directive. So there is nothing awful. When a beginner gets more experience he will not use this directive.:)